# PhoneGap change page is working but data not displaying in page

Tags: cordova

When I click on link change page function is working but that page not displaying any data. That page is dynamic. Is there anybody who knows this issue?

Below is my first page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#idLogout').click(function(){

     //alert(' button clicked ');        
     $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: SITE_URL+"logout.php",
           data: "&action=logout",
           success: function(msg){               
               //alert('Response = '+msg);
               var obj = $.parseJSON(msg);
               var rs = obj.result;
               //alert( rs[0] );
               if(rs[0] == 1)
               {
                   //alert('logged out success');
                   window.localStorage.removeItem("cookie_user_id");
                   window.localStorage.removeItem("cookie_profile_id");
                   window.localStorage.clear();

                   window.location.href = "login.html";
               }
               else
               {
                   alert('Could not logout!');
               }    
           }
         });
       return false;
    });


    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: SITE_URL+"logout.php",
           data: "&action=get_username",
           success: function(msg){               
               //alert('Response = '+msg);

               var obj = $.parseJSON(msg);
               var rs = obj.result;
               //alert( rs[0] );

               if(rs[0] != 0)
               {
                    $('#idspanUsername').html('Logged in as '+rs[0]);                            
               }

           }
         });


  });
  function change_page()
  {
    $.mobile.changePage( "faq_categories.html", { transition: "slideup",reloadPage:true,changeHash:true,type: "post" } );
    $("#list_categories").trigger("pagecreate");
  }
  </script>
```

```
<div data-role="page" id="more_page">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                More...
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true">
                <li data-theme="c">
                    <a  onclick="change_page();"  href="#"><!-- faq_categories.html -->
                        FAQs
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li data-theme="c">
                    <a href="about.html">
                        About
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div style="margin-top: 80px;">
                <p style="text-align: center; ">
                    <span style="font-size: small; " id="idspanUsername">
                        Logged in as...
                    </span>
                </p>
            </div>
            <a data-role="button" data-theme="b" href="javascript:;" id="idLogout">
                Log Out
            </a>
        </div>
        <div data-theme="e" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="nav-bar">
            <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top" class="nav-bar">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="track_dash.html" data-theme="e" data-icon="track" data-corners="false" data-iconshow="true" data-wrapperels="span">
                            <span class="foot_font">Track</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="calendar.html" data-theme="e" data-icon="cal" data-corners="false" data-iconshow="true" data-wrapperels="span">
                            <span class="foot_font">Calendar</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="shopping_list_type.html" data-theme="e" data-icon="shop" data-corners="false" data-iconshow="true" data-wrapperels="span">
                            <span class="foot_font">Shopping</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="profile.html" data-theme="e" data-icon="profile" data-corners="false" data-iconshow="true" data-wrapperels="span">
                            <span class="foot_font">Profile</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="more.html" data-theme="e" data-icon="more" data-corners="false" data-iconshow="true" data-wrapperels="span" class="ui-btn-active">
                            <span class="foot_font">More</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I clik on Faq that is below my second page.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        var datastring;
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:SITE_URL+'faq_categories.php',
            data:datastring,
            success:function(msg)
            {
                   var data = $.parseJSON(msg);
                   var rs = data.result;
                    var i=0;
                    for(i=0;i<rs.length;i++){
                        var category = rs[i].Name;
                        var category_id = rs[i].ID;
                        $('#list_categories').append('<li data-theme="c"><a href="faq_listing.html?c_id='+category_id+'">'+category+'</a></li>');
                    };
                    $('#list_categories').listview('refresh');

            }
        });
    });

    </script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

```
    <div data-role="page" id="faq_categories">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h3>
                FAQ Categories
            </h3>
            <a data-role="button" rel="external"  id="back_history" data-rel="back" data-theme="b" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left">
                Back
            </a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
                <p style="margin-left: 15px;">
                    I have a question about...
                </p>
            <ul data-role="listview"  id="list_categories"  data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this page is displayed but data not.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever i use change page event, I always used trigger event. See the below example,

```
$.mobile.changePage($('#listpage'));
$("#listpage").trigger("pagecreate");
```

But i dont know how its work with your code. If you have still problem, please post the full source.

Comment: When i am using changePage function page is loaded but data is not loaded.Please tell me how to load data ?

Comment: please add the source code for adding data. How you load data to that page?

Comment: please check my question now.

Comment: in that page i got only html code.My jquery function $(document).ready(function()}); is not calling

Answer (score 0):

You can give a parameter to reload the page, maybe that helps?

e.g.

```
$.mobile.changePage('page2.html', { dataUrl : "page2.html?parameter=123", data : { 'paremeter' : '123' }, reloadPage : true, changeHash : true });
```

Maybe here is a nice link http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/passing-data-between-pages-in-jquery-mobile/